# Data is not showing in NG Bootstrap table after calling a service in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, ng-bootstrap

I am using the [Angular Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) library to develop my application. I have used the Angular Bootstrap Table to create a page to show some information which is sortable and searchable. So I have followed this [link](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/table-complete.ts).

The bellow service has the code to call API to fetch the data. I can print the data into the console. But whenever I call the service in my component the data is not shown in my component.

**Service:**

```
interface SearchResultUserRegistrationInfo {
    userLists: UserRegistrationInfo[];
    total: number;
}

interface UserRegistrationState {
    page: number;
    pageSize: number;
    sortColumn: SortColumnUserRegistrationInfo;
    sortDirection: SortDirectionUserRegistrationInfo;
}

const compare = (v1: string | number | boolean, v2: string | number | boolean) => v1 < v2 ? -1 : v1 > v2 ? 1 : 0;

function sort(userLists: UserRegistrationInfo[], column: SortColumnUserRegistrationInfo, direction: string): UserRegistrationInfo[] {
    if (direction === '' || column === '') {
        return userLists;
    }
    else {
        return [...userLists].sort((a, b) => {
            const res = compare(a[column], b[column]);
            return direction === 'asc' ? res : -res;
        });
    }
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserRegistrationService {
    private apiPATH = 'account/';
    public _search$ = new Subject<void>();
    private _userInfoLists$ = new BehaviorSubject<UserRegistrationInfo[]>([]);
    private _total$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

    private _state: UserRegistrationState = {
        page: 1,
        pageSize: 5,
        sortColumn: '',
        sortDirection: ''
    };

    constructor(private service: ApplicationService) {
        this._search$.pipe(
            debounceTime(200),
            switchMap(() => this._search()),
            delay(2000)).subscribe(result => {
                this._userInfoLists$.next(result.userLists);
                this._total$.next(result.total);
            });

        this._search$.next();
    }

    // getter functions
    get userInfoLists$() { return this._userInfoLists$.asObservable(); }
    get total$() { return this._total$.asObservable(); }
    get page() { return this._state.page; }
    get pageSize() { return this._state.pageSize; }

    // setter functions
    set page(page: number) { this._set({ page }); }
    set pageSize(pageSize: number) { this._set({ pageSize }); }

    set sortColumn(sortColumn: SortColumnUserRegistrationInfo) { this._set({ sortColumn }); }
    set sortDirection(sortDirection: SortDirectionUserRegistrationInfo) { this._set({ sortDirection }); }

    private _set(patch: Partial<UserRegistrationState>) {
        Object.assign(this._state, patch);
        this._search$.next();
    }

    private _search(): Observable<SearchResultUserRegistrationInfo> {
        const { sortColumn, sortDirection, pageSize, page } = this._state;

        // server call
        let allMemberLists: UserRegistrationInfo[] = [];        
        this.service.get<AccountListResultInfo>(`${this.apiPATH}lists`).subscribe(data => {
            if (data) {
                allMemberLists = data.Accounts;
                console.log("========== From Service ==============");
                console.log(allMemberLists);
            }
        });

        // 1. sort
        let userLists = sort(allMemberLists, sortColumn, sortDirection);

        const total = userLists.length;

        // 3. paginate
        userLists = userLists.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, (page - 1) * pageSize + pageSize);

        return of({ userLists, total });
    }   
}
```

In this service the below line can print the data.

```
console.log("========== From Service ==============");
console.log(allMemberLists);
```

**Component:**

```
export class UserRegistrationListComponent implements OnInit {
userInfoLists$: Observable<UserRegistrationInfo[]>;
total$: Observable<number>;

@ViewChildren(UserRegistrationInfoSortableHeader) headers: 
QueryList<UserRegistrationInfoSortableHeader>;

constructor(
    public service: UserRegistrationService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {      
    this.userInfoLists$ = this.service.userInfoLists$;
    this.total$ = this.service.total$;
        
     console.log("---------- In component1 -----------------");
     console.log(this.userInfoLists$);

    this.service.userInfoLists$.subscribe(data =>{
        console.log("---------- In component2 -----------------");
        console.log(data);
    })      
}
```

}

Here the below code in **ngOnInit** method which does not print the data. So my Table is not getting data.

```
this.userInfoLists$ = this.service.userInfoLists$;
this.total$ = this.service.total$;
            
console.log("---------- In component1 -----------------");
console.log(this.userInfoLists$);
    
this.service.userInfoLists$.subscribe(data =>{
   console.log("---------- In component2 -----------------");
   console.log(data);
})
```

Please help me to find the problem and solve it. Here is the console output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in how you've structured the _search() function and the delay(2000) you have in place in the observable pipeline.

---

In the _search function, the return of() is outside the API get subscription. Which means that the **return is firing first**, and **then** the code inside the API get subscription is getting executed.
allMemberLists is initialized to [ ]  so the return is firing away first with [ ].
But, you're seeing your expected order of console.logs because of the following timeline.

1. return is fired in _search() with [ ]. Code inside API get subscription not even triggered yet.
2. pipeline's switchmap catches the result of([ ]). But delay(2000) prevents the subscription's code i.e this._userInfoLists$.next([ ]) from executing just yet.
3. Code inside API get subscription is triggered by now and you get the ==From service== console.log with the data.
4. 2000 milliseconds have passed by now. And now the this._userInfoLists$.next([ ]) is triggered.
5. Finally the component2 console.log is seen. But with the [ ].

The solution is to AVOID putting timers like this for API calls. And avoid subscribing to the API get in _search. Instead use the pipe and map operators in your _search(). You can read up on how map() works in rxJS official docs.

```js
private _search(): Observable < SearchResultUserRegistrationInfo > {


    // ALL THE CODE GOES INSIDE THE server call     
    return this.service.get < AccountListResultInfo > (`${this.apiPATH}lists`).pipe(map(data => {
        const {
            sortColumn,
            sortDirection,
            pageSize,
            page
        } = this._state;
        let allMemberLists: UserRegistrationInfo[] = [];
        if (data) {
            allMemberLists = data.Accounts;
            console.log("========== From Service ==============");
            console.log(allMemberLists);
            let userLists = sort(allMemberLists, sortColumn, sortDirection);
            const total = userLists.length;
            userLists = userLists.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, (page - 1) * pageSize + pageSize);
            // map() operator will automatically convert the returned value into an observable for me
            return {
                userLists,
                total
            };
        } else {
            // In case data is null
            return null
        }
    }));
}
```

Let me know if it worked!